# R matrix regression

Tags: r

I have been working this example I found online for hours and cannot get the code correct to calculate more than one predictors. I have been doing a lot research on matrix operations in R but I am not that efficient in coding. I wrote it out in excel and have it working correctly but I am failing to convert all of my functions back to R code. I cannot solve for X2 and X3.

```
attach(mtcars)
lm = lm(mpg~hp+disp+ qsec,mtcars)
lm
## Create X and Y matrices for this specific regression
X = as.matrix(cbind(1,mtcars$hp))
X2 = as.matrix(cbind(1,mtcars$disp))
X3 = as.matrix(cbind(1,mtcars$qsec))
Y = as.matrix(mtcars$mpg)

## Choose beta-hat to minimize the sum of squared residuals
## resulting in matrix of estimated coefficients:
bh = round(solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y, digits=4)

## Label and organize results into a data frame
beta.hat = as.data.frame(cbind(c("Intercept","Height"),bh))
names(beta.hat) = c("Coeff.","Est")
beta.hat
```

Comment: Why do you define X2 and X3? You don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for this:

```
## Create X and Y matrices for this specific regression
X <- with(mtcars, as.matrix(cbind(1,hp,disp,qsec)))
Y <- as.matrix(mtcars$mpg)
bh <- round(solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y, digits=5)

rownames(bh)[1] <- "Intercept"
bh
#               [,1]
# Intercept 38.62221
# hp        -0.03464
# disp      -0.02847
# qsec      -0.38556

lm

# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + disp + qsec, data = mtcars)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp         disp         qsec  
#   38.62221     -0.03464     -0.02847     -0.38556
```